# What does the @routes map to in playframework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In the playframework samples I see the syntax:

```
<a href="@routes.Application.index" class="btn">Cancel</a>
```

Inspite of having a controller class called Application.index the above throws an exception. So I would like to know what does @routes expand to at runtime and where does it point to since I have modified the code quite a bit to remove some other routes. I need to remove this non existing route but I would like to know how play actually maps them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your exception is 'Compilation error[value save is not a member of controllers.ReverseApplication]', it means there need to be a route in conf/routes that uses the action 'routes.Application.index()'

Comment: Yes. Thats the exception and there is no rule that uses the above route in the routes file. SO I guess thats the issue then